# delete specific key from arr after performing copy

Tags: javascript

I tried to copy the original src arr into newArr and delete the object key ie header property, but unfortunately, its deleting original property from src arr,but i dont want to delete from the original arr, instead operation should perform only on copied array

expected output described below

```
let arr = [[{header:"first",tail:"three"},{header:"second",tail:"four"}],[{header:"first",tail:"three"},{header:"second",tail:"four"}]];

let newArr = [[{tail:"three"},{tail:"four"}],[{tail:"three"},{tail:"four"}]];
```

may i know the problem in the code
please refer below snippet

```
let arr = [[{header:"first",tail:"three"},{header:"second",tail:"four"}],[{header:"first",tail:"three"},{header:"second",tail:"four"}]];

let newArr = Object.assign([], arr);

for(let i=0;i<newArr.length;i++) {
  for(let j=0;j<newArr[i].length;j++) {
    delete newArr[i][j]["header"]
  }
}

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.assign` will not work for nested arrays :

```js
let arr = [[{header:"first",tail:"three"},{header:"second",tail:"four"}],[{header:"first",tail:"three"},{header:"second",tail:"four"}]];

let newArr = []
arr.forEach(e=>newArr.push(e.map(x=>Object.assign({},x))))

for(let i=0;i<newArr.length;i++) {
  for(let j=0;j<newArr[i].length;j++) {
delete newArr[i][j]["header"]
  }
}

console.log(arr)
console.log(newArr)
```

You have to clone actual objects inside nested arrays.

Comment: deleting key should only operate on newArr(copied arr) not on arr(source arr),its deleting from both

Comment: I do think this might be expensive in some cases where the data might be really large considering the time complexity

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a little explanation about why this occurs: The object (in this case Array) is being stored in memory, `arr` is only a pointer to that object in memory. 
And when you tried to make a different copy of that same object, you only made a new pointer to the same object with `newArr` you only made a new pointer(reference) to that same object in memory.

Something like this

arr ===========> [{}, {}, {}, ...] <=========== newArr

This means that any update you make through `newArr` to that Object would also reflect on `arr`, same happens if you made it through `newArr`

#### Solution:

There are different ways you can completely copy objects in Javascript without so that you have a whole different `copy of such an object in memory` my favorite is using JSON (others might not like this or have better methods). So let's get this done.

const arr = [{}, {}, {}, {}, ...]

const newArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr)); // this way you just made a whole different copy.

If you do anything to `newArr` now, it would not affect `arr` because `newArr` though currently having the same content as `arr`, does not refer to the same Object in memory.

### Update

Owing to the sometimes unpredictability and expensiveness of JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({})), you might want to consider using something like using the `spread`

### Spread

const newArr = [...arr];

Comment: use of `JSON.stringify` to stringify an array then, JSON.parse to again make it a `Javascript Object` just to make a copy of an array, it is very costly(for performance). Please use `Array destructuring` you'll love this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use map for it

```
let arr = [[{header:"first",tail:"three"},{header:"second",tail:"four"}],[{header:"first",tail:"three"},{header:"second",tail:"four"}]];

let newArr = arr.map(subArray => subArray.map(item => {
   const newItem = { ...item }
   delete newItem['header']
   return newItem
})) // [[{tail:"three"},{tail:"four"}],[{tail:"three"},{tail:"four"}]];
```

OR

```
let arr = [[{header:"first",tail:"three"},{header:"second",tail:"four"}],[{header:"first",tail:"three"},{header:"second",tail:"four"}]];

let newArr = arr.map(subArray => subArray.map(({tail}) => ({tail}))) 
// [[{tail:"three"},{tail:"four"}],[{tail:"three"},{tail:"four"}]];
```